# Better understanding of training parameter for Keras-Model call method needed

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'd like to get a better understanding of the parameter *training*, when calling a Keras model.

In all tutorials (like [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch)) it is explained, that when you are doing a custom train step, you should call the model like this (because some layers may behave differently depending if you want to do training or inference):

```
pred = model(x, training=True)
```

and when you want to do inference, you should set training to false:

```
pred = model(x, training=False)
```

What I am wondering now is, how this is affected by the creation of a functional model. Assume I have 2 models: *model_base* and *model_head*, and I want to create a new model out of those two, where I want the *model_base* allways to be called with `training=False` (because I plan on freezing it like in this tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/transfer_learning)):

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(150, 150, 3))
x = base_model(inputs, training=False)
outputs = head_model(x)
new_model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

What will in such a case happen, when I later on call `new_model(x_new, training=True)`? Will the usage of `training=False` for the `base_model` be overruled? Or will training now allways be set to True for the `base_model`, regardless of what I pass to the `new_model`? If the latter is the case, does that also mean, that if I set e.g. `outputs = head_model(inputs, training=True)`, that this part of the new model would always run in training mode? And how would it work out if I don't give any specific value for training, when I run the new_model like this `new_model(x_new)`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`training` is a boolean argument that determines whether this `call` function runs in **training mode** or **inference mode**. For example, the `Dropout` layer is primarily used to as regularize in model training, randomly dropping weights but in inference time or prediction time we don't want it to happen.

```
y = Dropout(0.5)(x, training=True)
```

By this, we're setting `training=True` for the `Dropout` layer for training time. When we call `.fit()`, it set sets a flag to `True` and when we use `evaluate` or `predict`, in behind it sets a flag to `False`. And same goes for the custom training loop. When we pass input tensor to the model within the `GradientTape` scope, we can set this parameter; though it does not have manually set, the program will figure out itself. And same goes to inference time. So, this `training` argument is set as `True` or `False` if we want layers to operate either `training` mode or `inference` mode respectively.

```
# training mode 
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
   logits = model(x, training=True) # forward pass

# inference mode 
al_logits = model(x, training=False)
```

Now coming to your question. After defining the model

```
# Freeze the base_model
base_model.trainable = False

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(150, 150, 3))
x = base_model(inputs, training=False)
outputs = head_model(x)

new_model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

Now if your run this new model whether `.fit()` or custom training loop, the `base_model` will always run in inference mode as it's sets `training=False`.